# IndexError tuple index out of range

Tags: python, django

I am getting

> IndexError
>
> tuple index out of range

the print in comment also gives ValueError
malformed node or string: ['(300, 600)']

```
dict3={'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)'], 'op': 'range'}} 
result = Product.objects.all()
for key, value in dict3.items():
    print(value['attri'])
    print(value['op'])  # print( ast.literal_eval(value['attri']))      

    if value['op'] is 'range':
        result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__{}'.format(key, value['op']): ast.literal_eval(value['attri'])})
    else:
        result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__{}'.format(key, value['op']): value['attri']})
        

print(result)
```

Comment: This is not a tuple: it is a *string* that contains the representation of a tuple. Furthermore `value['op'] is 'range'` is a very problematic check. `is` means **referential equality**. You should almost never use that.

Comment: Furthermore `'attri'` maps on a *list* of items. So in that case you need to use `value['attri'][0]` instead of `value['attri']`.

Comment: but your check is broken, so this will probably almost never fire. Do you understand the difference between *referential* equality and *value* equality?

Comment: But if I have multiple elements like  dict3={'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)','(900,1200)'], 'op': 'range'}} then what I am supposed to do

Comment: how's that you have tuples as strings? they're stored as strings?

Comment: @AakashPatel: well what do you *want* to do in that case?

Comment: @bobrobbob : Yes the tuples are stored as string

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem :  I am trying to create a Product filter I want to take union in case my dictionary is dict3={'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)','(900,1200)'], 'op': 'range'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to generate a *union*, so every value in the list of `'attri'` is a condition, and the fact that *one* is triggered is sufficient.

We have to solve the problem that `value['attri']` is a *list* of strings of tuples. We can do that by constructing a *mapping* over the elemenst. Perform `literal_eval` on all of them, and then make a *disjunction* of the corresponding conditions. Something like:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

dict3 = {'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)'], 'op': 'range'}} 
result = Product.objects.all()

for key, value in dict3.items():
    # use == instead of is
    vls = value['attri']
    if value['op'] == 'range':
        vls = [literal_eval(vl) for vl in vls]
    cond_name = 'attributes__{}__{}'.format(key, value['op'])
    conditions = reduce(or_, [Q(**{cond_name: vl}) for vl in vls], Q())
    result = result.filter(conditions)
```

This will produce the same *disjunctive* behavior for all other operators as well. Note however that the different items of `dict3` will have *conjunctive* behavior, since you perform a *chain* of `.filter(..)` actions, but you can use the same trick to make this disjunctive as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3 = {'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)'], 'op': 'range'}} 
result = Product.objects.all()

for key, value in dict3.items():
    print('attri:', ast.literal_eval(value['attri'][0]))
    print('op:', value['op']) 

    if value['op'] == 'range':
        rg = ast.literal_eval(value['attri'][0])            
    else:
        rg = value['attri']
    result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__{}'.format(key, value['op']): rg})

    print(result)
```